# Unmarshall csv into a java object

Tags: apache-camel

```
<route id="readCSV">
        <from uri="file:inbox?noop=true&amp;delay=10&amp;fileName=b.csv&amp;delete=true"/>
        <log message="${body}"/>
        <unmarshal ref="csvDataFormat"/>

        <process ref="listRead"/>
        <to uri="direct:ins"/>
    </route>
```

I have this route i read the file correctly but when i want to transform it into a java object the list is full of nulls.
What is my problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example: we have a CSV file with names of persons, their IQ and their current activity.

> Jack Dalton, 115, mad at Averell Joe Dalton, 105, calming Joe William
>
> Dalton, 105, keeping Joe from killing Averell Averell Dalton, 80,
>
> playing with Rantanplan Lucky Luke, 120, capturing the Daltons

We can now use the CSV component to unmarshal this file:

```
from("file:src/test/resources/?fileName=daltons.csv&noop=true")
    .unmarshal().csv()
    .to("mock:daltons");
```

The resulting message will contain a List> like:

```
List<List<String>> data = (List<List<String>>) exchange.getIn().getBody();
for (List<String> line : data) {
    LOG.debug(String.format("%s has an IQ of %s and is currently %s", line.get(0), line.get(1), line.get(2)));
}
```